# Software for taking notes on programming

Tags: class, programming-languages

What type of software is good for taking notes on programming?  For example, if I want to jot down different methods/functions that are useful for different things.  Ideally, the software would have  syntax highlighting.

The software would need to support Mac OS X.  I will most probably be using this for Objective-C/iPhone development and Ruby on Rails development.

I want something that can shift between ordinary text and coding syntax.  For example if I was to type:

> In order to create a rectangle in Objective-C with a name square use: (CGRect *) square...........

I would like the objective-C code to have syntax highlighting but not the rest of the text.

Thanks!

P.S. I use textmate generally for coding.

Comment: So... something like a text editor that does syntax highlighting? What specific language(s) are you targetting?

Comment: What environment will it be running on?

Comment: If you are just looking for syntax coloration, Notepad++ or even Gedit do that pretty well, but I guess you know them already... What features are you looking for that a regular IDE does not have ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do you use to keep notes as a developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756/what-do-you-use-to-keep-notes-as-a-developer)

Comment: Please see the edits to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Evernote. http://www.evernote.com/

Comment: Evernote is good for taking notes on coding?  Does it have syntax coloring whatsover?

Comment: Not in the app, but there is a workaround. http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/adding-syntax-highlighting-code-snippets-evernote

Answer (score 0):

I like notepad 2
http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html

Answer (score 0):

For a pc, if you want a fairly simple notepad like app with syntax highlighting, I'd pick TextPad... You can associate syntax files and "customize" as needed.  For a mac I'd pick BBEdit...

Comment: In addition, TextPad allows you to do things like "block selection" and macro creation easily.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use an editor for simple notes. If I'm on Linux, I usually choose gedit. If I'm on something else, Scite is nice. I think it's very specific to what your needs are. Are you looking for a document editor which happens to be able to do syntax highlighting also?

Answer (score 0):

I found that either a mind-mapping tool or a text editor with an outlining support are very suitable for this sort of notes. On OS X I'm using FreeMind, everywhere else - Emacs [org mode](http://orgmode.org/).